# Intent not passing data to BroadcastReceiver of AlarmManager

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I'm trying to pass data to BroadcastReceiver thru PendingIntent of AlarmManager

In the example I'm trying to pass a String and a Parcelable Object, however when I try to read them in the BroadcastReceiver I get null

**Activity**

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent (this, ReminderBroadcast.class);
i.putExtra("ROUTINE", r);
i.putExtra("MESSAGE", "Example string");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,1234,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000, pendingIntent);
```

**BroadcastReceiver**

```
public class ReminderBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG,"notification code is "+ getResultCode());
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "message is: "+ intent.getStringExtra("MESSAGE"));
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "routine " + ((Routine)(intent.getParcelableExtra("ROUTINE"))).getRoutineName());
    
    }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<activity android:name=".SetupNotificationActivity" />
<receiver android:name=".support.ReminderBroadcast" 
          android:enabled="true" />
```

This is driving me crazy, as all the solution found on the internet suggest to put PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT to solve the issue, but that seems not to work.

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: Your code works here. Tested with only one string. getResultCode(): 0. Which code did you expect?

Comment: Not expecting any particular code from getResultCode. I'm bothered by the fact i don't receive any string from the getExtra
But thanks for your answer
The fact that the code works on you make the riddle even harder :)

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who may incur in the same problem, I found the solution.

The issue was caused by a problem in the Parcelization of the item, which was however not creating any Exception.

So removed that everything worked fine

Thanks for the support